# Simple SQL Union 2 queries on the same table

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

Trying to get all rows where userid = 'me'

Then 2 newest rows where userid <> 'me'

Items:

```
Userid time
other2   11
other3   10
me       10
me        8
other1    8
other3    7
me        6
```

would return

```
Userid  time
me        10
me         8
me         6
other2    11
other3    10
```

**The results don't have to be in any order**

```
(SELECT * FROM Items WHERE userid='me' )
UNION ALL
(SELECT * FROM Items  WHERE userid<>'me' 
ORDER BY time DESC  LIMIT 2)
```

This only outputs 2 rows

Comment: SQL-Server or MySQL?

Comment: Your query looks correct.  The use of `limit` suggests MySQL, so I'm removing the SQL Server tag.

Comment: I agree with @GordonLinoff. See this [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ca405/1/0).

Comment: @FelixPamittan MySQL

Comment: where is proof ? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bda6b/1

Comment: You're absolutely right, after closer inspection I was entering the wrong value for 'me' and only the second query was putting out 2 rows. Should I delete or mark answered?

Comment: @baconcheese113 you can just answer your own question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sql was correct as shown above

```
(SELECT * FROM Items WHERE userid='me' )
UNION ALL
(SELECT * FROM Items  WHERE userid<>'me' 
ORDER BY time DESC  LIMIT 2)
```

Union All concatenates the two queries, and the parenthesis allow different WHERE/ORDER BY/LIMIT clauses.
Demonstrated here: 
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ca405/1/0